# A particle must have energy to interact with the Higgs field: as energy is a source of gravity, it already has mass so what does it need Higgs for?

Tags: gravity, standard-model, mass-energy, higgs

If a particle only can be said to exist if it has energy, if it already must have energy to be able to interact with the Higgs field (to acquire mass) but energy is a source of gravity (if it can be localized) so it already (acts as if it) has mass before it even can interact with the Higgs field, then what do we need Higgs for?

Moreover, if when all properties contribute to the energy -and hence to the mass of particles- then shouldn’t the Higgs field also have to provide particles with properties like electric and color charge?

Comment: If there was no Higgs (nor any condensing gauge group), the fermions would be massless.

Comment: If fermions would be massless then they'd be energyless, i.e., not exist at all. Though you might objects and say that photons are massless, yet contain energy; the problem is that if according to relativity

Comment: If fermions would be massless then they'd be energyless, i.e., not exist at all -nor would we exist to worry about such things. While you might objects and say that photons are massless, yet contain energy; if according to the photon’s own clock it has a zero lifetime, then it cannot be said to have energy, exist -never mind that models in which photons are used like quantum electrodynamics work so spectacularly well.

Answer (score 2):

There two distinct things about your question:
1. energy of a field, which is simply the kinetic and the potential energy
2. mass of a field, which is an interaction strength of the field by itself, so it is kind of potential energy if you like.

For example, in quantum field theory, a term as follows
$$
m \bar\Psi\Psi
$$
is a **mass term** of a fermion field $\Psi$ (like electron) in the potential energy. It is understood as if a field is created and then annihilated, then you would have a contribution as much as m to the potential energy.

So, when you express the equations of motion for that particle, you would obtain that its total energy has a mass contribution as follows:
$$
E^2 = p^2 +m^2
$$
where p is the 3-momentum.

On the other hand, instead of a mass term, you can have an interaction term of a scalar field (i.e. Higgs boson) as
$$
g \phi \bar\Psi \Psi
$$
where g is the coupling constant of the Higgs with the electron (Yukawa interaction). If the scalar field has a minimum nonzero expactation value in the vacuum, like $\langle \phi \rangle = \nu$, then the term becomes like a mass term with $m=g\nu$, and the Higgs boson is the fluctuation around the value $\nu$.

Therefore, instead of putting a mass parameter to the theory, you put a Higgs field and obtain the masses of all kinds of particles due to the fact that its vacuum expectation value is nonzero.

Of course the most important necessity of the Higgs boson is that it gives you the correct masses for W and Z bosons while it leaves the photon massless as expected. Otherwise you would have to postulate *a priori* that photon is massless and W/Z bosons have that particular masses.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

We live in the universe we find our selves in, and do experiments with the available materials. These experiments have established , in time of discovery sequence, gravity (Kepler, Newton), electromagnetism( Faraday ...Maxwell), strong interactions (seen as nuclear) and weak interactions ( seen in decays of nuclei as beta decay).

Once differential equations entered the modelling of physics data, and were used as predictive tools the models became complicated . As experiments progressed and  predictions of classical models failed to describe the new data, new models were sought. Quantum mechanics was invented to fit the microcosm data ( and not only, think superconductivity).

The continuous target  of theoretical models for physics is simplicity, and the beautiful format of Maxwell's equations, which united what eighteenth century physicist thought were two different forces: electric and magnetic. Unification of forces reduces the number of necessary constants and is much stronger in predictions, as for example Maxwell's equations "predicted"/clarified that light was a combination of electric and magnetic fields, not an independent observable.

In a nutshell, this obsession for unification of forces led to models for unifying, from the four forces listed above, the weak with the electromagnetic in one mathematical model using differential equations, because the [symmetries observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)) in particle data gave a strong hint that this could be done.

When the model was proposed it was necessary for the higgs mechanism to be invoked, just for the weak and electromagnetic, to posit that at very large energies the exchanged particles representing the forces, W and Z and photon, were all massless and [by a symmetry breaking mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) acquired the masses we now measure in our laboratory experiments. Below the symmetry breaking scale the **elementary particles** in the table acquire masses (specific and constant).

The masses of **composites of these**, protons, neutrons, ...  and the tables and chairs, are masses resulting from the four momentum vector additions of the constituents. The strong interaction exchange particle in the  current standard model always has a zero mass ( gluon) as it is never free in our energy regime.  The [proton bag](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/)

[image: myproton]

It includes innumerable gluon exchanges and quark antiquark creations. These  obey the quantum chromodynamic force , and there are calculations which give close to the mass of observed hadrons, in a theory [called lattice QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD).

The unification dream is strong in the theoretical researches, and it is proposed that at very high energy all three, weak, electromagnetic and strong are united in one force , as implied by the data from [coupling constants of the three interactions :](http://www.physicsmasterclasses.org/exercises/keyhole/en/projects/running_alphas.html)

[image: running]

Gravity, with which you start, is at the end of particle considerations. It  comes much later because it is such a weak [force compared](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) with the other three. The unification of all four forces is the [holy grail](http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/features/mythical/grail.html) of researchers in particle theoretical physics, called [Theory of Everything.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) TOE.

First of all gravity must be rigorously  quantized, and then a mathematical model found which will embed the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_(mathematical_formulation)),  higgs and all, and include gravity, and describe and predict  observations that depend on it.

In my opinion string theory theories are on the correct path, since they already have a niche for gravitons and gravitational interactions and can embed the standard model.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, all properties of particles are manifestations of a single quantity, of its energy, so they all -electric charge, color charge etcetera- contribute to its mass since energy is a source of gravity (if it can be localized).

Comment: you are off the mark. that is not within the mainstream physics knowledge

Comment: You still  haven't explained what is wrong with my question.

Comment: you have to understand my answer, you do not understand what the Higgs mechanism is, is what is wrong. It is a mechanism, not an interaction in the sense of feynman diagrams. It is like a change in coordinates, context.

Comment: As far as I know, an electron acquires mass by coupling with the Higgs field (see Oktay’s answer above): isn’t a coupling an interaction and doesn’t the electron need to have energy to be able to couple to that field? If it is the electric charge of a proton and electron which binds them in a hydrogen atom and this binding energy has an electromagnetic origin, then doesn’t the electric charge of the electron powering that binding, represent a quantity of energy -which, as it is a source of gravity, acts like mass?

Comment: As to unification: If according to Newton’s 3rd law, a force always equals the counterforce it meets or is able to evoke -whatever the origin of both forces-  we can say that the strength of what seem to be qualitatively different, independent forces -electric, strong force etc.- are different, of themselves, so to speak?

Comment: No, this coupling with the HIggs *field* is not an interaction. An interaction happens between *particles* created with creation and annihilation operators .Particles are  generated on fields , fields are a mathematical construct the way coordinates are a mathematical construct , necessary for the mathematical model, in this case the standard model.

Comment: Coupling of a field with another field is an interaction. The word coupling comes from classical mechanics in the sense that two variables are coupled to each other on their equations of motion. An interaction term in the Lagrangian involving two fields will produce coupled equations of motion for both fields. By the way, I disagree with the statement saying that fields are just mathematical constructs, because they are the operators we can measure, like electromagnetic fields. They are the most fundamental thing in our understanding of nature. Of course this could be discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün  it is the difference between necessary and sufficient, which I find many people do not have a clear understanding of.  It is necessary for an interaction to take place,  that a coupling for the forces involved to exist , but it is not sufficient. In particle physics an interaction needs energy input, real on mass shell particles input and output.

Comment: Yes, I agree on that, I had thought you completely dissociated the two concept.